# Why does Dynesty multiprocessing with ThreadPoolExecutor not use all cores?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, bayesian, pool, threadpoolexecutor

I am trying to run a simple example with nested sampling and `dynesty`.

I installed `dynesty` from github: https://github.com/joshspeagle/dynesty

---

### Computer Setup

OS: Mac OSX El Capitan (10.11.6)
CPU: 8 cores
RAM: 16.0 GB

gcc: 4.8.5 via `conda install gcc`

---

### Problem Setup

I ran the code below (simulate data, setup prior/likelihood, submit to `dynesty`.

To establish multiprocessing, I used `multiprocessing.Pool`, `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`, and `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I tried the code in `Jupyter Lab`, `ipython`, and (script) `python run_dynesty_test.py`.

**Problem:** The entire script runs fine; but dynesty/python *starts* using **all** of the cores; then it slowly starts to use less and less cores. Finally, after about 5 minutes, dynesty/python uses almost exactly 1 core.

**Evidence:** `htop` starts reading 780%, then 550%, then 350%, then 100% CPU -- and it stays at 100% CPU for the rest of the operation; except a once every other minute, `htop` will read ~250-300% CPU.

---

### Question

Why is dynesty/ThreadPoolExecutor/python/etc not using all of my cores all of the time?

---

### Code Snippet Involving Dynesty and Multiprocessing

```
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count()-1) as executor:

    sampler = dynesty.DynamicNestedSampler(
                            loglike,
                            prior,
                            ndim=ndims,
                            nparam=ndims,
                            bound='multi',
                            sample='unif',
                            pool=executor,
                            queue_size=cpu_count())

    sampler.run_nested(nlive_init=100,nlive_batch=100)

    res = sampler.results
```

---

### Full Script to Setup Test

```
from __future__ import absolute_import,\
              unicode_literals, print_function

from multiprocessing import set_start_method
set_start_method('forkserver')

import dynesty
import math
import os
import threading, subprocess

from sys import platform
from numpy import pi, sin, cos, linspace
from pylab import *#;ion()

from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

if not os.path.exists("chains"): os.mkdir("chains")

# plotting
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def gaussian1Dp(cube):
    center = cube[0]
    width  = cube[1]
    height = cube[2]
    return lambda y: height*np.exp(-0.5*(( (center - y) / width)**2))

np.random.seed(42)

param0a= -0.5
param0b= 0.5
param1a= 0.1
param1b= 0.1
param2a= 0.8
param2b= 0.8

yunc  = 0.1
nPts  = int(100)
nThPts= int(1e3)

xmin  = -1
xmax  =  1
dx    = 0.1*(xmax - xmin)

yuncs = np.random.normal(yunc, 1e-2 * yunc, nPts)
thdata= np.linspace(xmin-dx, xmax+dx, nThPts)

xdata = np.linspace(xmin,xmax,nPts)

ydata = model([param0a,param1a,param2a])(xdata) \
        + model([param0b,param1b,param2b])(xdata)

yerr  = np.random.normal(0, yuncs, nPts)
zdata = ydata + yerr

figure(figsize=(10,10))
plot(thdata, model([param0a,param1a,param2a])(thdata) \
        + model([param0b,param1b,param2b])(thdata))
errorbar(xdata, zdata, yunc*ones(zdata.size), fmt='o')
show()

def prior(cube):
    cube[0] = cube[0]*2 - 1
    cube[1] = cube[1]*2
    cube[2] = cube[2]*2

    return cube

def loglike(cube):
    modelNow = model(cube)(xdata)
    return -0.5*((modelNow - ydata)**2./yuncs**2.).sum()

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor,\
                               ProcessPoolExecutor

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if not os.path.exists("chains"): os.mkdir("chains")
    n_params = len(parameters)
    ndims = 3

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=cpu_count()-1) as executor:

        sampler = dynesty.DynamicNestedSampler(
                                loglike,
                                prior,
                                ndim=ndims,
                                nparam=ndims,
                                bound='multi',
                                sample='unif',
                                pool=executor,
                                queue_size=cpu_count())

        sampler.run_nested(nlive_init=100, nlive_batch=100)

        res = sampler.results

from dynesty import plotting as dyplot

# evidence check
fig, axes = dyplot.runplot(res, color='red',
                lnz_truth=lnz_truth,
                truth_color='black',
                logplot=True)

fig.tight_layout()

joblib.dump(res,'dynesty_double_gaussian_test_results.joblib.save')
```

Comment: Try with `ProcessPoolExecutor` instead of `ThreadPoolExecutor` as executor.

Comment: Hello @Darkonaut, I tried both -- as well as multiprocessing.pool, which also works. But thank you for replying.

All three had the same behaviour. So I assume it's either my MPI library (which should be OpenMPI); or it's how Dynesty uses the pool/workers.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dynesty but what generally could also be, is that the algorithm simply is not parallelizable completely and intermediate results would have to fan in at some point.

Comment: You can try https://johannesbuchner.github.io/UltraNest/ instead, with MPI.